# How do I return a string that is generated by iteration in a recursive function?

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue returning a string that maps the path taken to get to the end of a maze. The function takes a 2-d array maze of string values and an array of 2 elements that represent the starting point of the maze(eg. [0,0]). I am returning the correct path when the function is called once but the string is not reinitialized so I get multiple answers concatenated.
Code:

```
function mazeSolver(maze, index = [0, 0]) {
  if (typeof mazeSolver.answer == "undefined") {
    mazeSolver.answer = "";
  }
  const pointer = () => maze[index[0]][index[1]];
  if (index[1] < maze[0].length - 1) {
    index[1] += 1;
    if (pointer() === " " || pointer() === "e") {
      mazeSolver.answer += "R";
      if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;
      return mazeSolver(maze, index);
    } else {
      if (index[0] < maze.length - 1) {
        index[1] -= 1;
        index[0] += 1;
        if (pointer() === " " || pointer() === "e") {
          mazeSolver.answer += "D";
          if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;
          return mazeSolver(maze, index);
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (index[0] < maze.length - 1) {
    index[0] += 1;
    if (pointer() === " " || pointer() === "e") {
      mazeSolver.answer += "D";
      if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;
      return mazeSolver(maze, index);
    }
  }
}
const mySmallMaze = [
  [" ", "*", " "],
  [" ", "*", " "],
  [" ", " ", "e"],
];
console.log(mazeSolver(mySmallMaze));
```

*logs: "DDRR"*
*on second call: "DDRRDDRR"*

Comment: I see you have this: "`mazeSolver.answer += "D";`" <-- You should not be doing this: mutating shared data (i.e. you should not be using side-effects) in recursive functions, or in FP in general. Instead consider passing data in parameters by-reference (granted, this is difficult in JS), or by returning product-type values (i.e. tuples or `object` values).

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure I follow your first comment. `if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;` seems to directly return the answer. Can you expand a bit on your first comment?

Comment: @Cam You're right, I didn't notice any of the `return mazeSolver.answer` lines, _whoops_!

Comment: Hey @jsN00b, check out this resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions. One of your theories is right! Specifically, from that source: "In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object."

Comment: Thank you @Cam. Realized I was being a lazy ***** - and deleted my comment. I do really need to `RTFM`. Appreciate your guidance. :-)

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this, while still using your `mazeSolver.answer` approach, is to pass an extra parameter which tracks whether we're in a recursive call or not. If not, we reset the answer:

```
function mazeSolver(maze, index = [0, 0], top_level_call = true) {
  if (top_level_call) {
    mazeSolver.answer = "";
  }
  const pointer = () => maze[index[0]][index[1]];
  if (index[1] < maze[0].length - 1) {
    index[1] += 1;
    if (pointer() === " " || pointer() === "e") {
      mazeSolver.answer += "R";
      if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;
      return mazeSolver(maze, index, false);
    } else {
      if (index[0] < maze.length - 1) {
        index[1] -= 1;
        index[0] += 1;
        if (pointer() === " " || pointer() === "e") {
          mazeSolver.answer += "D";
          if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;
          return mazeSolver(maze, index, false);
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (index[0] < maze.length - 1) {
    index[0] += 1;
    if (pointer() === " " || pointer() === "e") {
      mazeSolver.answer += "D";
      if (pointer() === "e") return mazeSolver.answer;
      return mazeSolver(maze, index, false);
    }
  }
}
const mySmallMaze = [
  [" ", "*", " "],
  [" ", "*", " "],
  [" ", " ", "e"],
];
console.log(mazeSolver(mySmallMaze));
```

That said, a more common and standard approach would be to just pass around the answer itself as a method parameter:

```
function mazeSolver(maze, index = [0, 0], answer = "") {
    ...
    answer += "R";
    ...
    return mazeSolver(maze, index, answer);
    ...
    return answer

}
```

There are at least a couple reasons to prefer the second approach:

1. In the second approach, all the inputs needed by the recursive function are in one place: parameters. This is easier to understand than the first approach, where some inputs are in the parameters and one is stored as a property on the object itself.
2. Consider the behavior if we assign `mazeSolver` to another variable: `let solver = mazeSolver`. Now `solver` is storing data on `mazeSolver`, which is messy and counterintuitive.